# Nginx call script before every request

Tags: nginx

I need to run a script from nginx (preferably PHP) before every request. All my served pages are plain HTML. Googling took me as far as LUA but, even though I have full access to server I would rather not change anything apart from nginx configuration (either `http` or `server` blocks).

I have `php5-fpm` also running on-site.

The reason is, we would like to allow developers do create HTML static one-page-apps that would need to AJAX post to an external API. CORS and all setup fine, all good, but we wanted to initiate a session on the destination API server.

Comment: What do you want the script to change?

Comment: I'll use the script to start a session on the destinaiton API server (basically cURL to it)

Comment: Yeah, the Lua module can handle that just fine. Of course you know those are scripts embedded inside your nginx configuration files.

Comment: yes, I'm starting to get frustrated already with googling for an alternative to Lua. Probably that's the only way!?

Comment: You could abuse `auth_request` for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To whom it may interest, I ended up using the following solution (Thanks to all the comments that helped me follow along):

- Configured NGINX to process HTML as PHP
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258524/unable-to-run-html-files-on-nginxphp-fpm
- Used php5-fpm `auto-prepend` to "prepend" a specific php file on every request, as [seen here](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file), but be careful with CGI caching. Better use different php5-fpm pool for vhosts using this technic.

Hope this can help someone.

**Note:** As alerted in comments, this has a significant impact on performance, because nginx will not serve static files anymore as it will need to send them back and forth to PHP-FPM.

Comment: Be aware that this has a significant performance penalty, from having to process static files with a script interpreter, and so it is unlikely to scale very well.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Does it perform worst compared to processing a normal script file like `php` ?

Comment: It probably won't be too bad, as long as there isn't actually any PHP code in the file. In that case it just has to read it and spit it back out at the browser. But that's still much slower than simply having nginx send the file with the kernel-accelerated `sendfile()` call, which is what it normally does when serving a static file.

Comment: @MichaelHampton right, ok then. Avoiding PHP code inside our files was a priority, of course performance too. So I guess this is still is good solution if I can't recompile nginx with lua. Thanks for the comment Michael.